# Kernel-Mode driver debugging of a physical Machine

Tags: driver, windbg, kernel-mode

On one computer I run Windbg.exe
I want connect to this computer an another physical computer
And on the other computer install and debug a driver I wrote it.

Is this possible and how?

It should be noted that already I checked my driver on virtual machine and everything works great, but the only physical machine, has a blue screen, so I want to debug the physical machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible. You can connect to the target machine using a [serial port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556867(v=vs.85).aspx), [Firewire](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556866(v=vs.85).aspx), [USB 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556869(v=vs.85).aspx) or [USB 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439372(v=vs.85).aspx) (requires special hardware support, special cable, and I heard it doesn't work more times than it does) or the preferred way if you're using Windows 8 or higher - [over Ethernet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346(v=vs.85).aspx).

You use `bcdedit` on the target computer exactly like you did on your VM and you pass `kd.exe` or `windbg.exe` a kernel connection string just like you did when you were debugging your VM - only with another transport.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to debug physical machine. As conio provided information for this. You can also follow Microsoft guidelines for setting up debug environment.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439378(v=vs.85).aspx